# Mongoose/MongoDB - Can I find a document by mapping through an array of ids that it contains?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document model that contains an array of user objects. What I want to do is return the document if that array contains an object with a specific user `_id`. Is this possible?

Something like

```
{
  _id: 1
  name: 'Document with Array of User Ids'
  arrayOfUsers: [
   {
     name: 'John Doe',
     _id: 2
   },
   {
     name: 'Michael Scott',
     _id: 3
   }
 ]
}
```

And then returning all documents that have an `_id` of 3 in `arrayOfUsers`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation like so:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/iu0f68D1vbL

```
Model.find({
  "arrayOfUsers._id": 2
})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field